# Square Root of the Square of a Negative Number

Tags: square-numbers

We define Square Roots as
$$\sqrt{x^2} = \left|x\right| = 
\begin{cases} 
  x,  & \mbox{if }x \ge 0 \\
  -x, & \mbox{if }x < 0. 
\end{cases}$$

However, if we take the Square Root of the Square Negative Number like $\sqrt{\left(-x\right)^{2}}$, a conflict arises.

For example, $\sqrt{\left(-5\right)^{2}}$ can be written as $\sqrt{25} = 5$.

Or we could write it as $\left(-5\right)^{2\cdot\frac{1}{2}} = \left(-5\right)^{1} = -5$. Both arguments seem logical to me.

I also thought about using the imaginary unit $i$. It gives me $\sqrt{5^{2}}\cdot i^{2} = -5$ which agrees with my second argument.

---

I am sorry if this question is too stupid. I can't make up my mind about which of those are correct.

Comment: You can't say $(-5)^{2\cdot\frac12}=(-5)^1; $ cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I would say for non-negative $y$ we define $\sqrt y$ as the non-negative solution $u$ of $u^2=y,$  and we don't define $\sqrt y$ for negative $y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't say $((-5)^2)^{\frac12}=(-5)^{2\cdot\frac12}.  $  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10) and answers there, which explain that fractional powers of negative numbers are not uniquely defined, and the "rule" $(a^m)^n=a^{m\cdot n}$ does not always work when $m$ and $n$ are not integers.

Comment: Why are you saying $(-5)^{2 \cdot \frac 12}\neq (-5)^1$?  Following the order of operations, we simplify the exponent and then exponentiate.  We don’t have a fractional exponent there.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw: I guess I meant you can't say $((-5)^2)^{\frac12}=(-5)^{2\cdot\frac12}$

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

We have no any conflict:
$$\sqrt{(-x)^2}=\sqrt{x^2}=|x|.$$
$$\left((-5)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=25^{\frac{1}{2}}=5.$$
If we want to use the property $$a^{xy}=\left(a^x\right)^y$$ so we need $a>0$ by definition.