# Formal Definition of Exponentiation (Rational Exponent)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, number-theory

This question has bothered me for a long time...

I know some people define $(-8)^\frac{1}{3}\approx 1 +1.73i$ referring to root with the minimum argument by De Moivre's Theorem. For this question, I want to stick with the [Calculus definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root) where $(-8)^\frac{1}{3}=-2$. [Note I do not know what the Calculus definition actually is here.]

> $\textbf{Question:}$ What is the "well-defined" definition for $a^c$ in "Calculus" where $c$ is a rational number? I'm not trying to sound harsh, but the "middle school" answer that $\sqrt[e]{a^d}:=a^\frac{d}{e}$ is not what I'm looking for the following reason.
>
> > Mathematically speaking, defining $\sqrt[e]{a^d}:=a^\frac{d}{e}$ where $d\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $e\in \mathbb{Z}^{\neq 0}$ would require the following theorem below to state such a definition actually makes sense. I provide a counterexample for the Thm below which means the definition does not work. So, what is the actual definition for $a^c$?

**Thm:** Let $c,d,e,f$ be integers where  $d,f\neq 0$. If $\frac{c}{d}=\frac{e}{f}$, then $\sqrt[d]{a^c}=\sqrt[f]{a^e}$.

**Counterexample:** Clearly, $\sqrt[2]{(-1)^2}\neq \sqrt[3]{(-1)^3}$.

Comment: [Fractional powers of negative numbers are not uniquely defined, and the "general rule" $(a^m)^n=a^{m\times n}$ does not always work when $m$ and $n$ are not integers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10/3219039#3219039)

Comment: In calculus we only define $b^q$ if $b > 0$ and then we prove there is exactly one *positive* root to $c^n =b$.  And then we *do* prove that theorem.

Comment: I understand that already. I'm looking for something a little more detailed. I wasn't responding to you fleablood.

Comment: It's only in complex numbers that we come up with alternative definitions so that a negative base can be used.

Comment: Wouldn't it be usual to write $(-1)^\frac{1}{3}=-1$ without involving complex numbers? Can you explain more about the first theorem you stated, I'd be curious to look at that too.

Comment: I think $(-1)^3 = -1$ and that is unique real so that $c^3 =-1$ so we can use the notation $(-1)^{\frac 13} = -1$ but I don't think such is every formally *defined* in calculus.  When it comes to actually defining exponents I think calculus only defines for positive bases.  I think.

Comment: I am going to have to break out a calculus textbook to be sure how we actually to this.  I think we do do the naive root definition *when* it exists though.

Comment: Lol I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For real numbers the equation $x^n = b$ will, if $b\ne 0; b\ne 1$

1) If $b >0$ and $n$ is even have exactly two solutions $x = c$ for some $c > 0$ and $-c$.

1b) If $b > 0$ and $n$ is odd then there will have exactly one solution $x = c$ for som $c > 0$.

2) If $b < 0$ and $n$ is odd then there will be exactly one solution $x = c$ for some $c < 0$.  Furthmore $|c|$ will be the solution to $x^n = |b|$.

2b) If $b < 0$ and $n$ is even there aren't any solutions.

And its easy to see that:  $c > 0$ is solution to $x^n = b^m; b>0;b\ne 1$ and $c$ is also a solution to $c^p = b^q$ if and only if $\frac mn =\frac qp$ and $c$ is a solution to $x^{pn}= b^{mp} = b^{nq}$.

Therefore a formal definition of $b^{\frac ab}$ can be and usually is the one you consider niave and informal.

> If $q = \frac mn$ and $m$ and $n$ are in lowest terms then $b^q = \sqrt[n]{b^m}$ assuming either $b \ge 0$ or if $b < 0$ then $n$ is odd.  Otherwise if $b < 0$ and $n$ is odd this is not defined.

Note your theorem *for positive numbers* allows us to make the specification that we put $q$ in lowest terms.

=====

Note: we completely overhaual this definition when we develop real exponents or complex numbers.

We only actuall need these for analyzing polynomials and rational functions.  And even then we can probably get away without using it most of the time.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for this thorough answer! For the theorem in yellow, say we were assuming $b<0$. Then, the only case that needs to be considered for that theorem to work is when $n$ is odd looking at $\sqrt[n]{b^m}$ (so $m$ could be even or odd). What is the case that is not defined when that happens? I'm just having a little trouble on the wording there. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

For a coherent answer, you really have to go via complex numbers.

The answer is that $a^c = \exp(c \log(a))$, where $\log(a)$ is a number $b$ such that $\exp(b) = a$.  The problem is that this is multi-valued, because $\exp(2\pi i)=1$.
Now $\exp(x+iy) = \exp(x) (\cos(y) + i \sin(y))$ (where $x$ and $y$ are real) is real if and only if $\sin(y)=0$, i.e. $y = \pi k$ for some integer $k$.

If $a < 0$, the values of $\log(a)$ are $\ln(|a|) + (2n+1)i \pi$ for integer $n$.
The corresponding value of $a^c$, where $c$ is real, is if and only if $(2n+1)c$ is an integer.  Thus $a^c$ has a real value if and only if $c$ can be written as a rational number with odd denominator.