# What's wrong with this reasoning? $((-2)^2)^\frac{1}{2} = (-2)^1 = -2$ vs $((-2)^2)^\frac{1}{2} = 4^\frac{1}{2} = 2$

Tags: exponentiation

We can, although not in very formal way, prove the property $((x)^b)^a$=$(x)^{ba}$ this way: 
$((x)^a)^b=(x)^a*(x)^a*…*(x)^a$ which is a product of $b$ number of $(x)^a$ terms.
$\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space=(x*x*…*x)*(x*x*…*x)*…*(x*x*…*x)$ where $(x*x*…*x)$ is a product of $a$ number of x terms. We can now conclude that this expansion equals $(x)^{ba}$ since multiplication is associative. But this is proof for $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$. How would you prove this formula for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ if it can be proved?

Comment: The problem is the base of the power that must be $>0$. Infact $((-2)^2)^{1/2}=[(-2)^{1/2}]^2$, where $(-2)^{1/2}$ is undefinite in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Well your example shows that it cannot be proved for rational exponents : if it could, then $-2=2$ !

Comment: Fractionary exponents are defined only positive numbers, and the usual formulæ for roots consesuently are valid only for positive numbers.

Comment: $f(x) = |x| := +\sqrt{ (x^{2})}$

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10)

Comment: Precise the base must be greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I don't know why I haven't already stumbled upon this till now. I'll play with this more and see what's going on. As for now, thank you for pointing some things out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have stumbled upon the reason why the rule
$$
(x^a)^b = x^{ab}
$$
either requires $x>0$, or it requires $a, b$ to be integers (specifying what is valid at $x = 0$ requires additional care, as then it's not fractional exponents that are problematic, but *negative* exponents). This is the resolution to your issue: when you say $((-2)^{2})^{1/2} = (-2)^1$, that expression simply doesn't fulfill the requirements we set on well-behaved exponential expressions, and thus it's not a valid equality.

On the other hand, $((-2)^2)^{1/2} = 4^{1/2} = 2$ is entiely valid, because that's how parentheses work.

As for how to prove $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$ for general real $a, b$ and $x> 0$, that depends entirely on how you define $x^a$ in the first place. If you're using continuity, then it follows directly from a standard continuity argument. If you have defined $x^a$ as $e^{a\ln x}$, then it follows from standard logarithm manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

brackets need evaluated first. BEDMAS, remember?
in this light, $((-2)^2)^\frac{1}{2}=(4)^\frac{1}{2}=2$

therefore,$((-2)^2)^\frac{1}{2}\ne(-2)^{2\cdot\frac{1}{2}}$