# Solution to $(-1)^{2x}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

So I encounter this problem when studying quantum mechanics:

> (-1)<sup>2x</sup>=1, find the set of values of x

Obviously, x ∈ {Z}, as 2x is even for all integral x.

Just to be rigorous, I wrote down the steps and come out with something like this:

> (-1)<sup>2x</sup>=1
>
> [(-1)<sup>2</sup>]<sup>x</sup>=1
>
> 1<sup>x</sup>=1, so x can be any real numbers.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Non-integer powers of negative numbers are not well-defined

Comment: WA says this here $$c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\land \left(x=1-\frac{i (2 i \pi  c_1+i \pi )}{\pi }\lor x=-\frac{i (2 i
   \pi  c_1+i \pi )}{\pi }\right)$$

Comment: $(-1)^{x} = 1$ if x is a rational number in lowest terms with even numerator.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner But if there's nothing wrong with my steps why does it give wrong answer?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10); the "general rule" $(a^m)^n=a^{m×n}$ does not always work when $ m$ and $ n$ are not integers.

Comment: @The99sLearner there *is* something wrong with your steps: you cannot blindly apply the same basic exponent rules to non-integer powers of negative numbers.

Comment: Maybe use $(-1)^{2x}=\exp(2x\log(-1))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that non-integer powers of negative numbers are not uniquely defined,

and the "general rule" $(a^m)^n=a^{m\times n}$ does not always work when $m$ and $n$ are not integers.