# Complex power of exponential function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

In my homework I have given quite often this complex function to integrate on
$$
\gamma(t)= e^{2i\pi t}
$$
with $t\in[0,1]$ real. Now what I am asking myselfe is, isn't this
$$
\gamma(t)= e^{2i\pi t}=(((e^i)^{\pi})^2)^t=((-1)^2)^t=1^t=1
$$
But this seems... very unlikely right?

Comment: The exponentiation rule $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ doesn't work in complex numbers.

Comment: Ah, thx Andrew! Of course.

Comment: It's a generalization of the problem that $$-1=(-1)^1=(-1)^{2/2}=\left((-1)^2\right)^{1/2}=1^{1/2}=1.$$

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10)