# Is this a valid property for complex exponentials?

Tags: complex-numbers

Suppose we have the complex exponential $e^{jx}.$

I manipulate the exponential as follows:

$e^{jx} = (e^{j2\pi})^{\frac{x}{2\pi}} = 1^{\frac{x}{2\pi}} = 1.$

My question is if the power property in the first equation is valid.

Also if you can provide some additional information or theory about that it would be appreciated.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10); the general rule $(a^m)^n=a^{m\times n}$ does not always work when $m$ and $n$ are not integers

Comment: Im studying about fourier series and a lot of computation of this kind needs to be done. Does that mean I will have to remember when the rule works? Because I havent seen any reference about that in the textbook im using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the general rule $(a^m)^n=a^{m\times n}$ for real $a>0$ or when $m$ and $n$ are integers.

In other situations, it could lead to nonsense such as $-1=(-1)^1=((-1)^2)^{1/2}=1^{1/2}=1$.