# Can I say that $1^{\frac{1}{2}} = (e^{2i\pi})^{\frac{1}{2}} =e^{i\pi} = -1 $?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Can I say that $1^{\frac{1}{2}} = (e^{2i\pi})^{\frac{1}{2}} =e^{i\pi} = -1 $ ?

the Answer is obviously no, but why not ?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10);  the general rule $(a^m)^n=a^{m×n}$ does not always work when $m$ and $n$ are not integers

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can see it as the solution of a complex equation where the the complex number $z$ and $-z$ are both solutions.