# Squaring the square root of a negative number

Tags: radicals, square-numbers

My maths teacher claims that $(\sqrt{-4})^2$ is not defined if we consider only those numbers in the real number plane.

Even if we exclude imaginary numbers, IMO the statement can be written as

$$-4^{(2 \times \frac{1}{2})}$$

Then the powers obviously cancel and we are left with $-4$. Even [using WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28-4%29%5E2) results in $-4$.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Identities_and_properties), $(b^n)^m = b^{nm}$ for all $b \neq 0$. This is what makes me not believe my teacher's claim, even if we are not considering complex numbers.

My teacher's logic is that we need to first evaluate $\sqrt{-4}$ before we can proceed with squaring the result. He also claims that the $(b^n)^m = b^{nm}$ identity is true only for $b > 0$, contradicting what Wikipedia states.

So, my two questions, summarized:

- Is $(\sqrt{-4})^2$ defined if we do not consider complex numbers?
- Is $(b^n)^m = b^{nm}$ for only $b > 0$ or $\forall$ $b \neq 0$?

Comment: If you only consider real numbers, $\sqrt{-4}$ is not defined, neither is any function of that, so the square of $\sqrt{-4}$ cannot be defined either.   The operations have to make sense in the order they are to be performed.

Comment: For the second question, cf. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10)

Comment: @Paul ok, so, if I understand what you're saying, $\frac{\sqrt{-4}}{\sqrt{-4}}$ will be undefined as well, right?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Hmm, ok, I think that answers my whole question, because my complete reasoning behind $(\sqrt{-4})^2$ being defined is the exponents cancelling. If that cannot be done, then, well, I understand where I went wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that expression will also be undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $\sqrt{-4}$ is not defined in real numbers, so neither is $\sqrt{-4}^2$
- That Wikipedia page says $(b^n)^m=b^{nm}$ for **integer** exponents $m$ and $n$.

When $b<0$, it may not hold for fractional exponents such as $\frac12$ (as in your case).