# Why is $(-1)^\frac{6}{2}$ not equal to $\sqrt{(-1)^6}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know it's wrong, because that would imply -1 = 1.
Shouldn't the property $a^\frac{b}{c} = \sqrt[c]{a^b}$ be applied here?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The rule $(a^m)^n=a^{m×n}$ does not always work when $m$ and $n$ are not integers; cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10)