# Where is the mistake? $-1=(-1)^{2/2}=\left(\left (-1\right)\displaystyle ^2\right)^{1/2}=1^{1/2}=\sqrt 1=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fake-proofs

Where is the mistake?
$$-1=(-1)^{2/2}=\left(\left (-1\right)\displaystyle ^2\right)^{1/2}=1^{1/2}=\sqrt 1=1$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! Not really I see it here, though.

Comment: The problem is that the formula $x^{\alpha \beta}=(x^{\alpha})^{\beta}$ is valid for $\alpha,\beta \in \Bbb Q$ only if $x>0$. And here you used exactly this property for $\alpha = 2, \beta =1/2$ and $x=-1$ therefore your equality is wrong.

Comment: @Surb $1/2\in Q$

Comment: Thank you for the responses! @Surb, but why $x^{\alpha\beta}=(x^\alpha)^\beta$ only if $x>0$?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10)

Comment: @aarbee yes, this is what I said, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each $=$ but the second is clearly right. That the second $=$ is wrong proves $\color{blue}{x^{a/b}=(x^a)^{1/b}}$ admits counterexamples with $x<0$. We use $x>0$ in the manipulation$$(x^{a/b})^b=x^a\implies\color{blue}{x^{a/b}=(x^a)^{1/b}},$$which is our only reason to expect the blue part to be true.