# Fallacy involving Euler's formula

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, fake-proofs

If
$$
e^{ix} = \cos{x} + i \sin{x}
$$
which means
$$
e^{2\pi i} = \cos{2\pi} + i \sin{2\pi} = 1 + 0i = 1
$$
and
$$
a^{(bc)} = (a^b)^c
$$
then why is this wrong for some real number $x$?
$$
e^{ix} = e^{2\pi i(x/2\pi)} \\
= (e^{2\pi i})^{(x/2\pi)} \\
= 1^{(x/2\pi)} \\
= 1
$$
?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10):  fractional powers of negative numbers are not uniquely defined, and the "general rule" $(a^b)^c=a^{b×c}$ does not always work when $b$ and $c$ are not integers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "rule" $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$ simply does not hold for complex numbers. Indeed, it doesn't even hold for all real numbers (consider $a=-1$ and $b=2$ and $c=\frac12$).

This is a great example of how, as mathematicians, we need to remember more than just the equations we learn—we need to remember the precise conditions under which the equations hold.

Comment: So when can I count on the rule being true?  I assume if $a$ is a positive real and $b$ and $c$ are real.  Also if $b$ and $c$ are both integers, right?  When else?  What if one of $b$ or $c$ is an integer?