# Why is $f(x)$ undefined for negative $x$ on Maple and my calculator but defined on WolframAlpha?

Tags: calculus, exponentiation, real-numbers

$f(x):=x^{4/5}\cdot (x-4)^2$

Maple gives me the graph:

[image]

WolframAlpha gives this [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%29%5E%284%2F5%29%28x-4%29%5E2&assumption=%22%5E%22+-%3E+%22Real%22)

and my calculator gives *Error 2* if I plug in $(-1)^{4/5}$.

My original intuition would be to think that the graph would be defined for negative $x$, but clearly something else is going on, what is going on in this case?

Comment: fractional powers of negative numbers are not uniquely defined; cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10)

Comment: Wolfram likely interprets $x^{4/5}$ as $(x^4)^{1/5}$. In general, fractional powers of negative numbers are undefined over the reals.

Comment: Many answers on this site give $(-1)^{4/5}=\left((-1)^4\right)^{1/5}=1^{1/5}=1=(-1)^4=\left((-1)^{1/5}\right)^4$ so in what way is it undefined?... @J.W.Tanner I'm reading the link currently as I'm typing this comment

Comment: Again, the numerator _4_ is even while the denominator _5_ is odd, so as P.Frost's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10) states it is definable for this case, so it is undefined because in _general_ fractional powers of negative numbers are undefinable? I don't get why I can't define it for _this_ particular case

Comment: You're right that $x^{4/5}$ is a well-defined real-valued function on the real line. The question really is, why do Maple and your calculator not know this? It presumably comes down to respective algorithms for math libraries and when they throw NaN. You may have more luck on a computation-oriented site...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I was reviewing curve sketching in Stewart Calculus and they go over a very similar function $f(x)=x^{2/3}(6-x)^{1/3}$ (Example 7, section 4.3, Calculus Early Transcendentals 7E) and they do in fact sketch the graph for $x<0$! The explanation they give (Example 7, Section 1.4) as to why some graphing calculators exclude graphing the function for $x<0$ is due to some machines compute roots using a logarithm, which is not defined for negative $x$.