# Explain how does $1 = i\;$?

Tags: complex-numbers, fake-proofs

Start with the expression
$$\sqrt[4]{81\mathrm{p}^3\mathrm{q}^5}$$

Simplify to
$$3q\sqrt[4]{\mathrm{p}^3q}$$

Assume $p = i, q = i$. Evaluate.

$$\sqrt[4]{81\mathrm{p}^3\mathrm{q}^5} = 3$$

$$3q\sqrt[4]{\mathrm{p}^3q} = 3i$$

Therefore, $3 = 3i, 1 = i$.

I suspect something related to absolute value, but can't figure it out at this moment.

Comment: Consider a simpler example, $\sqrt{(-1)^2}$. By your logic, this would be equal to $-1$. However $\sqrt$ is defined as the positive square root, and is equal to $1$. The correct way to pull something out of a square root is $\sqrt{a^2b}=|a|\sqrt{b}$. The same goes for $\sqrt[4]$ as well.

Comment: Exponentials and roots with complex numbers don't quite work the same as real valued stuff.

Comment: This is a very common mistake

Comment: $i^4=1$ and $1^4=1$. This does not mean that $i=1$. They are different numbers on the unit circle.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10)