# Why are we permitted to evaluate fractional exponents in two different ways?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

As I moved through algebra, I was taught that fractional exponents could be evaluated in one of two ways:

$$ x^\frac{a}{b} = (\sqrt[b]{x})^a = (\sqrt[b]x^a)$$

However, suppose $x=-2$ and $a=6$ and $b=4$:

If we evaluate using the first expression, we get:

$$(\sqrt[6]{-1})^4 = DNE$$

This is because we cannot take the even root of a negative number.

But, if we evaluate using the second expression, we get:
$$(\sqrt[6]x^4) = 1$$

Any explanation on what is going on? Thanks!

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10-fractional-powers-of-ne)

Comment: We have had (dozens of) questions on the failure for negative numbers of the laws of exponents for positive numbers. Please search for those earlier questions.

Comment: How is the search going, Late?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is not responding.