# Incorrect formula on Wikipedia?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

There might be an incorrect formula mentioned in the article [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) on [Wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org/).

The formula I'm talking about is this:

$\delta_{nm}=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^Ne^{2\pi i\frac{k}{N}\left(n-m\right)}$

After I simplified this formula (the right side), because I saw that there was $e^{\pi i}$ which could be turned into $-1$, it came out so that $\delta_{nm}=1$ which is obviously incorrect. So I'd like you guys to look into it just in case I'm wrong.

Comment: The exponent also contains $2 \cdot \pi \cdot i$, so $e^{2 \cdot \pi \cdot i} = 1$ and $1^{z} = 1$. The problem here is that for complex $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ it is not always true that $e^{z_{1} \cdot z_{2}} = \left( e^{z_{2}} \right)^{z_{2}}$ applies.

Comment: Please see [MSE Question 3219025](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10-fractional-powers-of-ne?noredirect=1&lq=1). Identities of powers that hold over real numbers do not generally hold over the complex numbers. In particular, $(x^a)^b=x^{(a\cdot b)}$ does **not** generally hold in the complex numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula is fine, the limit is the limit of a Riemann sum, and it equals
$$
\int_0^1e^{2\pi i t(n-m)}\,dt,
$$
which indeed gives $\delta_{mm}$.

It is not true in general, for $z,w\in\mathbb C$, that $e^{zw}=(e^z)^w$.

Answer (score 1):

It is like the classic example
$$
i=i^1=i^{\frac{4}{4}}=(i^4)^{\frac{1}{4}}=(1)^{\frac{1}{4}}=1
$$
Whilst actually
$$
i^{\frac{4}{4}}\neq(i^4)^{\frac{1}{4}}
$$
It matters on the $\gcd$ of the two terms.
For example:
$$
i^{\frac{3}{4}}=(i^3)^{\frac{1}{4}}
$$
Since $\gcd(3,4) = 1 $, but $\gcd(4,4)=4$.