# Proving $e^{i \theta} =1$

Tags: complex-analysis, fake-proofs

Let $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi) $ we have that
$$
e^{i\theta} = \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^\frac{2\pi}{2\pi} = (e^{2\pi i})^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}} 
$$
so as $e^{2\pi i}=1$ we have that
$$
e^{i\theta} = (1)^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}} =1
$$
But there must be something wrong because $e^{i\pi}=-1 \neq 1$.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10-fractional-powers-of-ne)

Comment: Yes, so by having the $\frac{1}{2}$ power, you're actually taking a square root, right? Well, the square root of 1 is *normally* 1 by convention, but really there are two solutions to this, yes? -1 or 1. Truly, the issue here seems to be that you said squaring a number and taking the square root always gives you that value back, but in truth it gives you the absolute value of that number back, i.e. turning -1 into 1